# Given two possible dictionary keys, how to take the one actually set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am receiving from an API a dictionary, but the problem is that sometimes I get `{value: test}` and others `{key: test}`. I am using a try/except block to take the one set:

```
try:
    var = received_dict['value']
except KeyError:
    var = received_dict['key']
```

Is there a better way to do that in Python 3?

Comment: you can use `in` to test membership. if `"key" in received_dict` and so on.

Comment: Shorter: `received_dict.get("value", received_dict.get("key", ""))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
received_dict.get('value', received_dict.get('key', False))
```

Comment: Hmm, this just uses False as a default if neither key is present. Throwing an exception might be better.

Answer (score 4):

This will still throw an error if neither key is present which is almost certainly the desired behavior.

```
received_dict.get('value', received_dict['key'])
```

However, python generally uses the: Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission mentality. If one of those occurs more frequently than the other how you're currently doing it may be best. If it really is 50/50 however using a get might be a cleaner way to go.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html (See EAFP)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest your approach seems good. If you want a bit more control over the different cases you can do this:

```
vars = [received_dict[key] for key in ["value","key"] if key in received_dict.keys()]
if not vars:
    raise KeyError("No 'value' or 'key' keys exist in dictionary")
elif len(vars)==2:
    raise KeyError("Both 'value' and 'key' keys exist in dictionary")
else:
    var=vars[0]
```

The only advantage of this approach is that it throws an error also when both keys exist. If you don't care about the "both exist" error case and you don't mind a different type of error being raised when the "none exist" error case happens, then you can do the code below to have a one liner:

```
var = [received_dict[key] for key in ["value","key"] if key in received_dict.keys()][0]
```